# how to obtain a list of restore points?

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.2

i am implementing restore points using `pg_create_restore_point`, and will then have a set of scripts to enable my users to restore to one of these restore points. Clearly i have work to do with taking backups and archiving WALs etc, but this is all in hand.

my question is, is there a database table which lists all the available restore points?

cheers
dave

Comment: Not sure, but maybe pgbarman can help you with that http://www.pgbarman.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. `pg_create_restore_point` just calls `XLogRestorePoint(...)` after a bunch of sanity checking, to write the restore point record to the transaction logs. Restore point information is only referenced in `recoveryStopsAfter(...)`, which is part of recovery.

I'm not really sure how PostgreSQL would expose restore points in the catalogs anyway. How would it know a restore point was obsolete and could be removed?

I suggest tracking this yourself using a regular table, where your system deletes from it when it purges old WAL. Your table should contain the restore point name and the LSN (xlog location) at which the point was created. That way you can delete old restore points when you purge the corresponding backups.

So, something like:

```
INSERT INTO my_restore_points (rpname, rplsn)
VALUES
('some_restore_point', pg_create_restore_point('some_restore_point'))
```

The other way to do it would be to use `pg_xlogdump` to scan xlogs for restore points, but that'll be slow and clumsy. Plus I'm not sure 9.2's pg_xlogdump is good enough.

Comment: thanks for that, bit annoying but i can go for your own table insert solution

Comment: a follow up questions if i may, do you know if it's possible to remove a restore point? i'm concerned that my users may create more than one with the same name so i would want to remove the first once they create to avoid a restore going to the first one. thanks

Comment: No, it isn't possible. A restore point is an entry in the transaction logs, which are written strictly in order and never modified. You need to make sure your users don't do that. Don't use the raw user-generated restore point identifier; qualify it in some way.

Comment: Grep'ing for restore points in the logs is probably the easiest thing to use/get used to. E.g. `grep -R 'restore point'`